# R: Robust linear regression using a list having repeated number

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm using an rlm model like this.

```
fit=rlm(log(y) ~ x  + z)
```

Z is a list that contains all `1`. I get the error `Error in rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method,  :   'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'`

Is it equivalent to use `fit=rlm(log(y) ~ x  + 1)` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent to using `rlm(log(y) ~ x  + 1)` and actually it is best just to use just `rlm(log(y) ~ x)` because the intercept or the constant term (which is the variable containing only 1's) is included by default.

By writing `+ 1` you just "remind" `rlm` that you want the constant term in your regression, whereas writing `+ z` looks more like you have some variable that you want to add (and you might be unaware that it contains only 1's), but having both the default intercept and such a `z` that contains only 1's causes a problem - [perfect collinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), hence this gives an error.

It is strongly advised to always have the intercept in your regression, but if you really wanted to eliminate it, this could be done with `log(y) ~ x - 1`. Now actually `log(y) ~ x - 1 + z` works fine because there are no two identical variables.